# How to force a Table of Contents to start new page

Tags: table-of-contents

My table of contents is around 1 and 2/3 pages long, but the first page ends with

6.8 The Forecast . . . . . . . . . . . . . 54

7 Quality Control 57

7.1 Process Control . . . . . . . . . .  . . . 57

But I would like the

7 Quality Control

to start at the top of the second page to keep all of section 7 together, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add a `\newpage` via `\addtocontents` right before the seventh chapter:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\chapter{Quality Control}
```

Comment: Doing this only when the document is in "really final, no more changes, definitely" form. ;-)

Comment: At first this didn't work for some reason, then I realised it was a chapter and I am using sections. After that it didn't work either, so I placed the
    \chapter{Q...
next to the 
    ..ect\newpage}
and it worked, so thanks! :)

Comment: @DannyBland -- Also, keep in mind that a LaTeX has to be recompiled twice in order for the effects of commands such as `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` fully show up.

Comment: @egreg What about `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\goodbreak}`?  That should always do the right thing.