# Allow page breaks in the ToC after parts

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, parts

We use XeLaTeX to produce Large Print and have come across an issue when trying to produce a book with quite a few Parts where we only want to show the parts in the ToC. I have reduced it down to a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part[{1}]{1}
\part[{2}]{2}
\part[{3}]{3}
\part[{4}]{4}
\part[{5}]{5}
\part[{6}]{6}
\part[{7}]{7}
\part[{8}]{8}
\part[{9}]{9}
\part[{10}]{10}
\part[{11}]{11}
\part[{12}]{12}
\part[{13}]{13}
\part[{14}]{14}
\part[{15}]{15}
\part[{16}]{16}
\part[{17}]{17}
\part[{18}]{18}

\end{document}
```

This produces a Contents page which starts on page 2 as it can't fit on page 1 and doesn't want to split. In reality I'm using memoir and 25pt with 7 parts, but this example produces the same result. I've tried it in texlive 2014.
Is there a work around that doesn't involve manually inserting a ToC break where it needs to be. This is part of an automated system and the user doesn't have access to the TeX code, so I need a way to allow the page to split automatically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The problem essentially disappears when you include `\chapter`s in each `\part`.  Is `\part` really the correct subdivision for your purposes?

Comment: @AndrewSwann's comment gives the reason for no page break.  what you can do about it is covered in [How to force a Table of Contents to start new page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103998/579).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I do have `\chapter`s but then I have `\maxtocdepth{part}` so it gets the same result.

Comment: As I said in the question I am trying to find an automated way of doing it, Thanks.

Comment: If you have only parts and not chapters, maybe you could write the ToC entries as `chapter` level entries. Not the most elegant solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could update `\l@part` - the macro responsible for setting each `\part`-related entry
in the ToC - to insert a zero `\penalty` after each regular entry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\let\old@l@part\l@part
\renewcommand{\l@part}[2]{%
  \old@l@part{#1}{#2}% Regular setting of \part in ToC
  \pagebreak[0]}% Add a zero penalty (for possible page break)
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part[{1}]{1}
\part[{2}]{2}
\part[{3}]{3}
\part[{4}]{4}
\part[{5}]{5}
\part[{6}]{6}
\part[{7}]{7}
\part[{8}]{8}
\part[{9}]{9}
\part[{10}]{10}
\part[{11}]{11}
\part[{12}]{12}
\part[{13}]{13}
\part[{14}]{14}
\part[{15}]{15}
\part[{16}]{16}
\part[{17}]{17}
\part[{18}]{18}

\end{document}
```